# XMLSpy XSD to XSD mapping for many to one

Tags: xmlspy

I am using XMLspy to do XSD to XSD mapping in XSLT which is nothing but source schema to target schema
i need some XMLspy tool experts help on the following
1)i want to map one or more different elements  of source schema to same element of target schema
when i do the normal mapping using xmlspy , i get message that duplicate elements mapping or cancel
so how do i map one or more source elements to same target elements

2)i want to do xml file vaidation using schema in XSLT . 
such as the elements in xsd are enum values,. if i get any other values in xml other than schema enum values , i need to throw exception

3)in xmlspy , how do i use xml:when in the editor.i see only if condition not when

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first question about the many to one.  In your target schema you can right click a node and there is a option to create a duplicate entry for it, so it will look like:

```
Foo
Foo(2)
```

Then you can map a additional source to it.